# faces of imported objects have different reflective properties

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I've downloaded some car models, and after applying the scale on them, it became apparent that some of them have a narrower fresnel angle, so only the clearcoat is visible on most of the object.[image]
I've made up a simplified .blend file, which [i've uploaded here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15HcNVES_VITarbSsL6FB0tQkKPckW0_C?usp=sharing).
the two objects have the same topology, and are joined and using the same material slot, but the  left uses faces pulled from the car model, and the right uses freshly added faces.
[image]
It's also not affected by texture space, UV Mapping, or face orientation.

any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see if you enable the display of the normals, the cube on the left have inverted normals, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals:

[image]

It also has custom split normals data, which may create bad shading, maybe clear:

[image]

Comment: that's weird, I thought I'd checked face orientation, but obviously not; that seems to be the source of the problem.
thanks for your help!